# Fluent Nhibernate 3 Mapping Composite Field (Custom Type)

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, composite-id, custom-type

HI all, my scenario

```
public class Permission
{
    public virtual Function Function { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class MapPermission : ClassMap<Permission>
{
    public MapPermission()
    {
        Table("Permissions".ToUpper());
        CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Function, "FunctionID").KeyProperty(x => x.Profile, "ProfileID");

    }
}
```

Where Function AND Profile  are two easy mapped entities. When i Run i have this error:

Could not determine type for: Data.Model.Entities.Function, Data.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(FunctionID)"}

Is there a way to avoid this? ultimately i need to create a class with CompositeID made by two custom mapped classes. If i uses compositeID with int fields it works like a charm

Thanks in Advance

Function (Like Profile) Mapping

```
public class Function
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MapFunction : ClassMap<Function>
{
    public MapFunction()
    {
        Table("FUNCTIONS");
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **KeyReference** instead of **KeyProperty**

```
public class MapPermission : ClassMap<Permission>
{
    public MapPermission()
    {
        Table("Permissions".ToUpper());
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Function, "FunctionID")
            .KeyReference(x => x.Profile, "ProfileID");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark if this solved your problem.

Comment: It is located by my answer underneath the down arrow.